# Check if name ends by string in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

In my folder cache, i have dozens of files whose name is `filename-number.json`, like

```
sifriugh-80.json
dlifjbhvzique-76.json
dfhgzeiuy-12.json
...
```

I have a simple script that cleans my cache dir every 2 hours, deleting files older than 2 hours:

```
$fileSystemIterator = new FilesystemIterator('cache');
$now = time();
foreach ($fileSystemIterator as $file) {
    if ($now - $file->getCTime() >= 3 * 3600) // 2 hours
        unlink('cache/' . $file->getFilename());
}
```

Now, i'm looking to only delete every 2 hours files whose number (before `.json` but not if number is present at the beginning of the file) does NOT end by `-100.json`, and those ending by `-100.json`, every 7 days only.

I know that i can use `preg_match()` to get names, but is there any effective way to perform it?

Comment: So, you are " looking to only delete ...  files whose number ... does NOT end by `-100.json`, and those ending by `-100.json`" => do you mean you want to remove all files? Please clarify and share the `preg_match` code you tried with your expression  -  it will clarify it even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is much simpler way than regex using PHP 8+ `str_ends_with()` : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with.php

```
if (str_ends_with($file->getFilename(), '100.json)) {
    // unlink at needed time
} else {
    // unlink at needed time
}
```

For PHP 7, there are several ways to emulate it, check at the bottom of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with.php

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you should not use `preg_match`. It is so good here.
Before using `preg_match` you should check the first symbol in file name and skip the next code if it `is_numeric`.
If it is not numeric you need to get only ending "-" can be presented zero or ones + number 1 or more digits + .json ending
(pattern can be something like this `/-?\d+\.json$/`)
After that you can parse it and know the real number before .json,
Your verification will be something like

If "-" symbol exists and number is 100 check the date for 7 days

If number is not 100 check the date for 2 hours